# Interval between each posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My app got approved publish_actions.

I am trying to comment in feed post.

Everything is working fine.

Below is my working code.

```
function home(token){
 jQuery.ajax({
 url:'https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=id&limit=2&method=get&access_token='+token,
 dataType:'jsonp',
 success:function(data){
 post_comment(data,token);
 }
 });
 }

function post_comment(list,token){
 for(i=0;i<list.data.length;i++){
 jQuery.ajax({
 url:'https://graph.facebook.com/'+list.data[i].id+'/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=' + token,
     dataType:'script',
 success:function(){ 
 gonderildi += 1;
 if(gonderildi >= list.data.length){
 }
 }
 });
 }
 }
```

Output.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=XXXXXX.
 https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=XXXXXX.
```

I just need to set interval between each post.

Example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=XXXXXX.

Wait 5 sec.

https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=XXXXXX.
```

after 5 sec it should post another request.
help.

Comment: SetInterval? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: I tried that not much luck for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use closures for this, something along these lines:

```
function post_one_comment(id, token) {
       jQuery.ajax({
           url:'https://graph.facebook.com/'+id+'/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=' + token,
           dataType:'script',
           success:function(){ 

           }
       });
}

function post_comment(list,token){
    for(i=0;i<list.data.length;i++){
        (function(_id){
            setTimeout(function(){
                post_one_comment(_id, token);
            }, i * 5000);
        })(list.data[i].id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```js
function home(token) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=id&limit=2&method=get&access_token=' + token,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      post_comment(data, token);
    }
  });
}

function post_comment(list, token) {
  for (i = 0; i < list.data.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + list.data[i].id + '/comments?message=testing&method=POST&access_token=' + token,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function() {
          gonderildi += 1;
          if (gonderildi >= list.data.length) {}
        }
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. all posts at the same time. I want it to trigger next post after first.

Comment: This will not work since it will just create list.data.length number of timers all firing after 5000ms, not 5000ms after one another. Also, the i iterator will all get the same value in all the timers. Closures are needed.